# Hacer que una columna dependa de otra

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, trigger, insert

Necesito que al insertar una fila, un dato se actualice en funcion de otro. En este caso pretendo que numero2 se actualice para ser igual que numero1, pero el trigger no funciona

```
CREATE FUNCTION igual() RETURNS trigger AS '
BEGIN
  new.numero2:=numero1;
  return new;
END
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER igual AFTER INSERT 
        ON datos FOR each ROW
        EXECUTE PROCEDURE igual();
```

Al insertar nuevos datos da este error

```
ERROR:  no existe la columna «numero1»
```

Comment: ya probaste con `new.numero2:=new.numero1;`?

Comment: si, en ese caso no da error pero no se obtiene el resultado que quiero

Comment: Porque en lugar de una funcion no haces un update en el trigger

Comment: He estado probando y lo he conseguido arreglar poniendo `BEFORE INSERT` en el trigger